# ndk-build error without space in the path

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm trying to compile the Hello-jni sample but I still get this error :

```
*ERROR: You are using a non-Cygwin compatible Make program.
Currently using: C:/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r8e/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/make
To solve the issue, follow these steps:
1. Ensure that the Cygwin 'make' package is installed.
   NOTE: You will need GNU Make 3.81 or later!
2. Define the GNUMAKE environment variable to point to it, as in:
     export GNUMAKE=/usr/bin/make
3. Call 'ndk-build' again.*
```

First time I got this error, I found the issue about the space in the install directory (It was installed in c:\Program Files...). SoI moved it into C:/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r8e/ but I still got the error. Then I tryed to re-install cygwin (with the make package), android-NDK but the error is always here !

When I echo the $CYGWIN_GNUMAKE I have this :

```
   $ ndk-build NDK_LOG=1
HOST_OS=cygwin
HOST_ARCH=x86
HOST_TAG=cygwin-x86
GNUMAKE=/cygdrive/c/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r8e/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/make (system path)

CYGWIN_GNUMAKE=C:/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r8e/build/core/check-cygwin-make.mk:43: Android.mk hello-jni.c Android NDK: C:/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r8e/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/make is not cygwin-compatible. Stop.
Cygwin-compatible GNU make detected
make: /cygdrive/c/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r8e/build/core/build-local.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/cygdrive/c/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r8e/build/core/build-local.mk'.  Stop.
```

The strange thing is that here I have the message "Cygwin-compatible GNU make detected" but it still doesn't work. If somebody has an idea I would really appreciate, it has been two days now that I'm trying to fix it...
By the way, I'm a very beginner with linux shell :)

Comment: It fails because of spaces in windows directory paths.Check your path once again.Try to compile NDK with Windows compatible build process ndk-build.cmd. No need to use Cygwin to compile with the NDK

Answer (score 0):

Thanks swetha kini  for your help but, as I said, my directory's name does not contain space (ie. C:\AndroidNDK\android-ndk-r8e). Finally I found the issue : in the cygwin path "C:\AndroidNDK\android-ndk-r8e" was before "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin", I just swap and now it works.